# MS Chart draw barchart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bar-chart, mschart

I need to draw a histogram, and columns with minimum and maximum values ​​should have other colors that are different from other columns and have different widths! 
Now I have done this in two sets, but it's the wrong outcome.

Below is my code:

```
chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Blue;
int y;
for (y = 0; y < lbls.Length; y++)
{
 chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(costs[y]);
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel(y, y + 2, lbls[y], 0, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark));
}

 chart1.Series[1].Color = Color.Red;
 chart1.Series[1].Points.AddY(1500);
 chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel(y+4, y + 6, "lol", 0, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark));
```

its give me:
[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure how to change specific column width but and to change a specific `i` points color do the below.

```
'Loop through series to find min and max and then color label
Chart1.Series[0].Points[i].Color = Color.Red
```

**P.S.**

I'm not sure if you can change just one columns width. I sometimes use `Chart1.Series[0]("PixelPointWidth") = some integer` to change the width of column series but looking at the msdn page it seems it can only be applied to the series and not individual datapoints.

[PixelPointWidth @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456636%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You could just create a new series and add it to the chartarea with just the max and min values and then do `Chart1.Series[1]("PixelPointWidth") = some integer` to make them wider than the first series